# segue called twice when using DispatchQueue.main.async

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, grand-central-dispatch

I'm trying to perform a segue to a new view controller, but the segue is being called twice and the new view controller appears twice.
I'm using a method that performs a GET request to an API to retrieve data.
That method uses a completion handler.

```
func getSearchResultsForQuery(_ query: String, completionHandlerForSearchResultsForQuery: @escaping (_ success: Bool, _ error: NSError?) -> Void)
```

When the method completes successfully my segue is called, from within the main queue as is required.

I've set breakpoints so I could see what was going on and the execution jumps from the performSegue back up to the conditional that checks if the method was successful and then continues until the segue is called a second time. 
I've tried a purely programatic segue, but the result was the same.
I also added a print statement, and if I comment out the segue the print statement is only called once.

I've used this same pattern a number of times before and never had a problem with it and I just can't figure out why this is happening.
The only thing I'm doing different this time is using Swift 3 and using DispatchQueue.main.async instead of dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(). 
Here is the function which is giving me this problem:

```
    @IBAction func search(_ sender: UIButton) {

        let searchQuery = searchField.text

        TIClient.sharedInstance().getSearchResultsForQuery(searchQuery!) { (success, error) in

            if success {
                print("Food items fetch successful")
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    print("Perorming segue for food item: \(searchQuery)")
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showFoodItems", sender: self)
                }
            } else {
                print("error: \(error)")
            }
        }
}
```

Edit: I never found out what the problem was, but completely deleting the story board and recreating it solved it.

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't a great way to fix this issue, Also I can't leave a comment due to low reputation but what happens if you wrap the whole if statement in DispatchQueue.main?

```
 @IBAction func search(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let searchQuery = searchField.text

    TIClient.sharedInstance().getSearchResultsForQuery(searchQuery!) { (success, error) in
     DispatchQueue.main.async {
       if success {
         print("Food items fetch successful")
         self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showFoodItems", sender: self)
       } else {
         print("error")
       }
     }
}
```

Would that yield a different result or still the same result? checking for Bool doesn't require too much processing power so I don't think putting it in a main queue is a bad thing but I'd do this to trouble shoot. Sorry I can't just comment on this.

Comment: I just tried that, but it causes an error with the URLSession GET request.

Answer (score 0):

Check in storyboard, maybe you set segue from your button action instead of controller.

Comment: I checked and rechecked storyboard. I even deleted the storyboard segue and tried a programatic segue. Still had the same problem,